# integration of eclipse project with maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I imported a maven project in eclipse ide. When I am doing

> mvn clean install

getting the following errors

> non-resolvable parent pom failure to find http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show the content of the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: you configured multi-module project, and parent pom.xml is missed. Check `<parent>` tag in your pom.xml http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects

Answer (score 0):

Maven cannot find the parent of your pom.

You have 2 ways of fixing this.

Either run mvn clean install on your parent project first.
Or make sure the `<relativePath>...</relativePath>` of the parent is correctly set in the child pom.

If you still have the issue, post your poms, and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not able to find the setting.xml file from the default path of user Setting so their is two solution

1. Add the settings.xml file in the default location which is shown in the  Run COnfiguration e.g : [image]
2. Add the User setting path  where your maven/conf/settings.xml is present.

NOTE : Add the D:/mavenRepo attribute with some location where  you want  your maven download and store the depedency mention in pom.xml. As you can see i create a folder with name mavenRepo in D:/ drive for this.

do the clean install and your project will start working hope so.
 [image]